# Cannot set prop('selectedIndex') in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, selectedindex

So I have a select box -- that has a name but no ID -- and Firefox is not letting me change the 'selectedIndex' property.

I've tried:

```
$('select[name=foo]').prop('selectedIndex',1)
```

Also tried:

```
$('select[name=foo]').get(0).selectedIndex=1
```

Basically, anything I could possibly find relating to selectedIndex...but it refuses to change. It stays at 0. Tried this in my code, tried it in the console...it stays at 0. It works in all other browsers, though.

And the select box is dynamically generated, so I can't just stick an ID in there.

What's weird, though, is that the val() and text() properties do reflect that the option that was selected was actually selected, but the selectedIndex doesn't change, so I'm trying to force it to change.

Comment: So this is specifically a Firefox issue, and it doesn't affect other browsers?

Comment: why do you want to set the selected indexy

Comment: Yup: I've tried Chrome, Internet Exploder, Safari, and Opera, and it worked fine on all those.

Comment: Is there anything else unusual about the element? Is it disabled or hidden or anything?

Comment: isjustMe -- because the site I'm working on uses a custom-made select box formatter, and for some reason it's interfering with the proper operation with Firefox. (Changing the formatter is not an option at this point, as it's been made clear to me by TPTB.) I've found that when the formatter is active, drop-down options aren't recognized in Firefox unless you manually select the first option. Because of the way our code is, I can't just programmatically select the first option or else I'm in an infinite loop, so the other option is to change the selectedIndex.

Comment: And the thing is, if I do a console.log of the "val" and "text" properties, the VALUE and TEXT shows up as selected, but the selectedIndex is still zero, which is what's really effing with the code.

Comment: Oh, cripes...once I manually select the first element, it's letting me change the selectedIndex programmatically. Now if only I could do that BEFORE having to manually select....argghgh!!!!

Comment: When you say "manually", do you mean with a mouse event?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having the problem, but does `$('select[name=foo]').val('').prop('selectedIndex',1)` help at all? I'm not sure why it would, but it's worth a shot

Comment: And by the way - what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: If this is just a visual issue *(which it sounds like since you say the `.val()` and `.text()` are correct)*, then try setting some random style property, or other various things like that. Sometimes they just need a kick to trigger a redraw.

Comment: what do you see if you run this?
alert($('select[name=foo]').html());
We need to see the HTML code to help you

Comment: kdureidy -- I see:

<option value="">No option</option>
<option selected="selected" value="SS">AN OPTION</option>
<option value="RN">ANOTHER OPTION</option>

Ian -- we're using jQuery 1.7.

Crazy Train -- thanks for the suggestion; tried but didn't work. :(

Comment: Crazy Train -- yes, I mean with a mouse event. Actually, I'm thinking what I can do is on a $(document).ready() or something I can just put in some code that will look for all select boxes and programmatically select the first element in each...any suggestions?  :)

Comment: Try this `var n = 1; myselect.insertBefore(myselect.options[n], myselect.options[n+1]);`

Comment: ...if that doesn't work, try setting the `.selectedIndex` to `-1` before setting it to its desired value.

Comment: Okay, so what I tried was setting the selectedIndex to a STRING, and then suddenly it let me change the selectedIndex to whatever I want. However, the code STILL doesn't recognized the changed value, despite the fact that the selectedIndex, value, option selected flag, and option HTML all reflect that the change happened...

Comment: Oh, and CT -- I tried that "myselectInsertBefore" thing and just got back "options is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work, but could you do this instead, which should work:

```
$('select').find('option').first().next().prop('selected','selected');
```

To get n-th item:

```
index = 1;
$('select').find('option:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')').prop('selected','selected');
```

Where index is the selectedIndex

Are you sure this doesn't work on firefox?  Just tested it (firefox 21 on ubuntu) - http://jsfiddle.net/Wmv6q/

Perhaps you have something else on your page that is resetting it?  If not, can you tell what version of firefox you are on?

Comment: Thing is, it's not necessarily that I want the index to be 1 -- I might want it to be 2 or 3. Oh...and just for laughs, I tried that suggestion -- and...the index was still at zero.

Comment: You should set the `selected` property as `true` or `false`

Comment: No you shouldn't.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmv6q/1/ - if the attribute is present (even set to false), it is selected.  Setting it to true implies false would work to not select it.  The spec says selected implies that attribute value "selected", which is why I use it, but it is also correct to just have nothing after it.  Using false is definitely not correct.

Comment: dave: You're confusing attributes and properties. The property (which you're setting) should be set as a boolean value.

Comment: @dave Sorry, but you've already contradicted yourself. Properties are different from attributes. When setting the `checked`, `selected`, and `disabled` **properties**, you should use true/false. When setting the **attributes**, you should use a string. Have you ever worked with DOM methods/properties (not jQuery)? What's the result of `element.checked`? A boolean. What's the result of `element.getAttribute("checked")`? A string. Look at the jQuery docs for both `.attr()` and `.prop()`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value you can set it by that in FF pretty easily:

```
<select>
    <option>First</option>
    <option>Second</option>
</select>

$('select').val('Second');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbtDj/

Answer (score 0):

This is very bizarre, but with the help of who we generally consider our lead developer, found out that when our little select box formatter is in use, the code that does the updating is actually counting the `<div>`s and `<li>`s and other tags put in to format the box. The solution was to put in a line of code that forces ONLY `<select>` elements to be counted, and that was the root of the problem. All works now.

Why it was locking up the drop-down, though, I don't know!

Answer (score -2):

This works in Firefox 17.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.4, does it work on your platform too? If it does, the problem would indeed be some interference with another library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function test () {
            $('select[name=foo]').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        Should display 'one' after button click:
        <select name="foo">
            <option>zero</option>
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <button type="button" onclick="test()">set index to 1</button>

</body>
</html>
```